# Is there a solution more suited for storing this type of data?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to do some research regarding a data structure, but I'm not sure what name to search for.

Here is the hypothetical scenario:
I have a business with thousands of employees.
Each employee can report to multiple people above them (the tree branches out upwards) and also each employee can oversee many people below them (tree also branches out downwards).

Here are two very simplified tables of what I currently use:

```
employee (id, Firstname, Lastname)
employee_structure (id, ParentID, ChildID)
```

I use a recursive PHP function to display the tree of an employee (downwards tree direction).
But running a SELECT query on every level  to find the next level of each "node" is extremely time consuming.
This generates over 300 000 direct and indirect relationships. 
As the structure grows over time, this will only get worse.

I need to find out if there is solution (in MySQL, or even something else) that will be better suited for storing and retrieving structures like this.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, or give some helpful hints, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Materialized paths, nested sets

Comment: The Oracle database has some special functions built-in to simplify hierarchical retrievals as a single query

Comment: That is one crazy (hypothetical) organisation!

Comment: does mysql have an equivalent of common table expressions? that's pretty much what you want, a recursive sql query.

Comment: What do you want to know? The complete branch or just particles of data? Like parent/child/neighbour row?

Comment: Why would you ever want to return 300,000 rows?

Comment: In some cases I do need all 300,000 rows. I need to export a spreadsheet/csv with all direct as well as indirect relationships between employees.

Answer (score 0):

There is a m:n relationship between employees.
Using a connctiontable in you MySql database is right.

To display the tree you dont need to run a SELECT for each node.

Your query output should look like

```
+--------------------------------------+
| id | Firstname | Lastname | ChildIDs |
+--------------------------------------+
```

where `ChildIDs` is a `GROUP_CONCAT` value of the related IDs.

The query:

```
SELECT 
e.id, e.Firstname, e.Lastname, GROUP_CONCAT(c.ChildID) 
FROM employee AS e
JOIN employee_structure AS c ON c.ParentID = e.id
```

If the data is too huge and you run out of memory use some kind of paging to keep the result small.

Then you can loop through this result and display the complete tree without running another SELECT.

```
function printEmployees($id, $indent) {
    echo str_repeat(' ', $indent * 2) . $employees[$id]['Firstname'] . ' ' . $employees[$id]['Lastname'] . PHP_EOL;
    if (!empty($employees[$id]['ChildIDs'])) {
        foreach (explode(',', $employees[$id]['ChildIDs']) as $childID) {
            printEmployees($childID, $indent + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely this only returns the first level of the hierarchy below a named individual? While you could do a nasty join to self on this (INNER JOIN....ON CONCAT(',', copy2.group, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', copy1.id, ',%') ) it's far from efficient, although it's a bit faster than jumping in and out of PHP

Answer (score 0):

Most hierarchical models are based on the notion of trees (nested set, adjacency, threaded binary) - where each node only has a single parent. This is obviously not true in your case. As it stands you have a network model (considered using a graph database engine like [OQGraph](http://openquery.com.au/node/23)?).

As it stands you've got a big data integrity problem ensuring that the graph is acyclic (that someone is not their own boss). This can occur with a simple self join tree hierarchy but is much less likely due to the simpler data model, and easier to identify. The only way I know of to avoid this is to add an explicit attribute indicating the level for each employee - and each employee can only supervise staff at a lower level.

Leaving that aside for now (although the solution depends on the notion of a level, at least relative to the starting point) if it were me, I'd go with a temporary table and a recursive stored procedure, something like....

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE oversees (
   employee_id INT NOT NULL,
   level INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY employee_id
);

CREATE PROCEDURE populate_oversees(p_emp_id INT, p_max_levels INT)
(
   INSERT INTO oversees (employee_id, level) VALUES (p_emp_id, p_max_levels);
   call recurse_oversees(max_levels);
);
CREATE PROCEDURE recurse_oversees(p_level INT)
(
   INSERT INTO oversees o1 (employee_id, level)
   SELECT e.id, p_level-1
   FROM employee e
   INNER JOIN employee_structure es
   ON e.id=es.ChildId
   WHERE es.ParentId IN (
      SELECT o2.employee_id
      FROM oversees o2
      WHERE level=p_level
   );

   IF (p_level>1) THEN recurse_oversees(p_level-1);
);

SELECT *
FROM oversees
ORDER BY level DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks symcbean. I will have a closer look at your answer later today.

You mentioned that I must keep my data acyclic.
In this very weird hypothetical scenario, an employee can be his own boss. i.e. A is the boss of B, B is the boss of C, and the C is the boss of A. So indirectly, A appears to oversee himself.

So my hypothetical scenario of a company and it's employees is not the ideal scenario to describe my needs. But you seem to understand anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) article especially `The Nested Set Model` section. You also have good references at the end of the article.

It boils down to using `left` and `right` values (beside parent id) in your SQL table for representing tree node. What this approach enables you is to retrieve full tree, node path, all leaf nodes and more in a single query.

Down side of this approach is a bit more complicated inserting and deleting of nodes in a sense that you have to maintain `left` and `right` values properly.

Comment: 2MAS says the data is not hierarchical - he wants a hierarchical view of a network.

Comment: @symcbean Hmm, maybe you are right, didn't noticed the fact that employees don't have to be in strict hierarchy. This sentence in question is probably what lead me to neglect this `Each employee can report to multiple people above them (the tree branches out upwards) and also each employee can oversee many people below them (tree also branches out downwards).`